# Angularjs ng-repeat not updating when values are dynamically inserted via http request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting some data with http and updating the `$scope.comments` variable.Then I display it with ng-repeat however variable is updating correctly but ng-repeat is not working. Here is javascript:

```
$scope.updateComments = function(taskId){
    var contentInput = document.getElementById(taskId);
    contentInput.value = '';
    $http.get('/loadTask/'+taskId).success(function(task){
        angular.forEach(task.comments,function(comment){
            $http.get('/loadComment/'+comment).success(function(c){
                $scope.comments[comment] = c;
                console.log('Comments now',$scope.comments);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

I can't use `$scope.$apply` because it's already being called by `$http` request.
This is html:

```
   <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                {{comments}}
                <div class="comments" ng-repeat="comment in task.comments track by $index">


                    <p><a href="{{comments[comment].author}}">
                        {{comments[comment].author}}    
                    </a>{{comments[comment].content}}</p>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Also `{{comments}}` is updating correctly.
Can anyone help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: in your ng-repeat, you looped task.comments which is not a property of $scope

Comment: @PrinceG but I am accesing comments which is part of scope

Comment: yeah, but task.comments is only accessible inside your success callback. Basically you are looping an undefined variable in your ng-repeat -> `ng-repeat="comment in task.comments track by $index"`

Comment: @PrinceG oooh thank you very mach!

Comment: @Claies task.comments is array of mongodb ObjectId's. Those reffer to another colletion of comments.

Comment: as an aside...do you REALLY want to make a new $http request per comment?

Comment: @DavidL with the system I'm currently using I have no other options.